# SharePoint 365 content type hub

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

Ok I have read a few articles on here so far about a content type hub vs hub. Can someone please dummyfy the difference for me.

I am trying to get a content type to flow from my hub on SharePoint 365 to its connected sites. I am still just not wrapping my head around the content type hub.

edit: 
Can a modern communication site be a content type hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SharePoint Hub** site is kind of your organization portal, where the content/ news/ updates from all over the organization can be viewed. Also, when you add different sites under your Hub site it automatically adheres to the branding/ navigation used in the your Hub site. Plus you can 'Search' across all associated sites under your hub. **You can have multiple hub sites in your Organization.**

**Content type hub** is a special site in your SharePoint environment which will let you manage your content types from one place. So, when you create a content type in your 'Content Type Hub' and publish it then it will be propagated to all your site collection in your organization. There is only one content type hub in your SharePoint online tenant.

Comment: Will a 'content type hub' connect to all of your other hubs?

Comment: It will publish the content type to your entire tenant.